# increasing space on top of a piechart

Tags: java, jfreechart

Is it possible to increase the space on the top in a piechart i.e between the piechart and the upper outline.I did try using setInsets,setInteriorGap functions but i was not able to increase the space between the piechart and outline.Can anyone guide me.

the below image link shows a piechart where the piechart touches the upper outline
[image]

which i dont want it to

Comment: Code is better than English, please post it.

Answer (score 2):

You could try to set a padding around the chart like:

> public void setPadding(org.jfree.ui.RectangleInsets padding)
>
> Sets the padding between the chart border and the chart drawing area,
>
> and sends a ChartChangeEvent to all registered listeners.

[Source: JFreeChart Javadoc](http://www.jfree.org/jfreechart/api/javadoc/org/jfree/chart/JFreeChart.html#setPadding%28org.jfree.ui.RectangleInsets%29)

```
JFreeChart chart;

// initialize the chart

chart.setPadding(new RectangleInsets(50, 0, 0, 0));
```

Comment: I have accepted the answer @UmNyobe- thanks alot.